# The account of a team owner has been disabled. How can i promote another person to be the team owner?

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-teams

Recently, a team's manager quit, he was the owner of several teams in Microsoft Teams app. I disabled his domain account, and in turns there is no owner for those teams. The members in those teams asked me to promote one of them as the new owner. Is it doable? or should I create a new team in Microsoft Teams? Or enable the previous account to promote a person and then disable it again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding a new owner to the team is simple, but requires administrator permissions for Office 365.

1. In the Office 365 Admin Center browse to **Groups**.
2. Select the Team in question and display it's **properties**.
3. Under **Owners** click **Edit > Add Owners**.
4. Select a new owner and click **Save**.

Propagating owner change can last up to an hour.

There is a more detailed explanation covered in the blog post [Microsoft Teams: Help! The team owner left the company and we don’t know what to do!](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/skypehybridguy/2017/11/29/microsoft-teams-help-the-team-owner-left-the-company-and-we-dont-know-what-to-do/).